# Replacement For "Drive Someone Nuts"

Tags: expressions, idioms, formality

In the expression **to drive someone nuts**, I studied that it's possible to replace the word *nuts* with words like: *bananas*, *crazy*, *insane*, *bonkers*, ...

I'd like to know is this expression polite? If it is, which word-replacement is more common and polite?

Comment: When you start a paragraph with a `>` symbol, the Markdown system used on this site formats it like a quotation.  So please don't do that unless you really are quoting from another source.

Comment: @NateEldredge It's enough to drive you nuts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could say you ***drove me up the wall***.

That means the same and is very common in British English (and not impolite).

Answer (score 1):

All the expressions in the OP - *bananas, crazy, insane, bonkers* - are adequate stand-ins for "*nuts*". If by "polite," you mean "formal,"
then no, they are not polite, but colloquial (commonly used) expressions. An alternative: *the behavior was exasperating, it tested my tolerance, and "drove me to **distraction***.